# Multiple value checks using 'in' operator (Python)

Tags: python

```
if 'string1' in line: ...
```

... works as expected but what if I need to check multiple strings like so:

```
if 'string1' or 'string2' or 'string3' in line: ...
```

... doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
if any(s in line for s in ('string1', 'string2', ...)):
```

Answer (score 7):

If you read the expression like this

```
if ('string1') or ('string2') or ('string3' in line):
```

The problem becomes obvious. What will happen is that 'string1' evaluates to True so the rest of the expression is shortcircuited.

The long hand way to write it is this

```
if 'string1' in line or 'string2' in line or 'string3' in line:
```

Which is a bit repetitive, so in this case it's better to use `any()` like in Ignacio's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'string1' in line or 'string2' in line or 'string3' in line:
```

Would that be fine for what you need to do?

Comment: Ofcourse, thats what I tried but I needed a more readable and efficient method. :)

Answer (score 1):

`or` does not behave that way. `'string1' or 'string2' or 'string3' in line` is equivalent to `('string1') or ('string2') or ('string3' in line)`, which will always return true (actually, `'string1'`).

To get the behavior you want, you can say `if any(s in line for s in ('string1', 'string2', 'string3')):`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` and `lambda`

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["a", "d", "e"]
c = ["1", "2", "3"]

# any element in `a` is a element of `b` ?
any(map(lambda x:x in b, a))
>>> True

# any element in `a` is a element of `c` ?
any(map(lambda x:x in c, a)) # any element in `a` is a element of `c` ?
>>> False
```

and **high-order function**

```
has_any = lambda b: lambda a: any(map(lambda x:x in b, a))

# using ...
f1 = has_any( [1,2,3,] )
f1( [3,4,5,] )
>>> True
f1( [6,7,8,] )
>>> False
```

Answer (score 1):

---

1. You have this confusion Because you don't understand how the logical
   operator works with respect to string.

   Python considers empty strings as False and Non empty Strings as True.

   Proper functioning is :

   a and b returns b if a is True, else returns a.

   a or b returns a if a is True, else returns b.

   Therefore every time you put in  a non empty string in place of
   string1 the condition will  return True and proceed , which will
   result in an undesired Behavior . Hope it Helps :).

Answer (score 0):

also as for "or", you can make it for "and".
and these are the functions for even more readablity:

returns true if any of the arguments are in "inside_of" variable:

```
def any_in(inside_of, arguments):
  return any(argument in inside_of for argument in arguments)
```

returns true if all of the arguments are in "inside_of" variable:

same, but just replace "any" for "all"

Answer (score -1):

You can use "set" methods

```
line= ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]

# check any in
any_in = not set(["string1","string2","not_in_line"]).isdisjoint(set(line))

# check all in
all_in = set(["string1","string2"]).issubset(set(line))

print(f"any_in: {any_in}, all_in:{all_in}")
# Results: 
#    any_in: True, all_in:True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).